swift DeviceActivityReport run in background
DeviceActivityReport presents statistics for a device:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/deviceactivityreport
The problem:
DeviceActivityReport can present statistics with a delay for a parent device (when DeviceActivityReport is presenting, the DeviceActivityReportExtension is called to process the statistics). One possible solution is to call DeviceActivityReport periodically throughout the day in a child device. However, the app will not be available all day. Is there any way to run DeviceActivityReport in the background?
I have tried the following approach, but it didn’t work (DeviceActivityReportExtension didnt call):
let hostingController: UIHostingController? = .init(rootView: DeviceActivityReport(context, filter: filter))

hostingController?.view.frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 100, height: 100))

hostingController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
hostingController?.loadView()
hostingController?.viewDidLoad()
try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
hostingController?.viewWillAppear(true)
hostingController?.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
hostingController?.viewDidAppear(true)
try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
hostingController?.didMove(toParent: rootVC)
try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
hostingController?.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
hostingController?.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
hostingController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
hostingController?.view.layoutSubviews()        
hostingController?.endAppearanceTransition()

Is there any way to run DeviceActivityReport in the background? (when app is not visible/closed). The main problem is call DeviceActivityReport
